# gnuplot function not plotting - Order of Operation Issue?

Tags: function, plot, gnuplot

The gnuplot (Version 5.4 Windows patchlevel 5) for the function described in the first line below does not work, the second one does. What is going on?

```
plot  [0:2] [0:4] f(x) = 1/2/(pi*d)**0.5*exp(-1*(1-x)**2/(4*d)), d = 0.0065, f(x)
#plot  [0:2] [0:4] f(x) = 1/(2*(pi*d)**0.5)*exp(-1*(1-x)**2/(4*d)), d = 0.0065, f(x)
```

The above two lines are the narrowed down version from several alternatives involving sqrt instead of **2.

Comment: Haven't we had the same question already recently? And wasn't it already answered in the comments? This is the "old" gnuplot pitfall: **integer division**, i.e. `1/2=0`. Use `f(x) = 1.0/2/... ` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the "everlasting" gnuplot pitfall: integer division, i.e. `1/2=0`. Use for example `f(x) = 1.0/2/...` instead.

Comment: Is this an "everlasting" bug or is there some reasoning here? Thanks for the very fast reply that I was not expecting. As a non mathematician it is much appreciated.

Comment: @4gottenMyMaths No, this is no bug, this is a feature! It is done this way, because some programming languages do it this way. You just have to be aware to avoid such "surprises".